# Change CSS rule for small screen with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, sass, themes

I am making **bacon menu** for small screens. I need to initialize menu without showing menu links, so I hide them with `jQuery`. The problem is that on big screen menu links are still hidden and I don't want that to happen.

I use this code to avoid menu link removal on big screens, but it's not working:

**scripts.js**

```
      $(window).resize(function(){     
        if ($(window).width() > 720 ){
          $('ul.menu').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
          $('ul.menu').css('display', 'inline-block');
          // $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
        }
      });

      //$('ul.menu').css('display', 'none');
      $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
          $('ul.menu').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else {
          $('ul.menu').css('display', 'none');
        }
        });
```

**SASS**

```
    .menu
      li
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       background-color: #fff;
       @include media($medium-screen-up) 
         list-style-type: none
         display: inline-block
         float: right;
         margin: 0 10px 0 10px
         @include position(relative, -50px null null null)
         background-color: initial;
```

Comment: Don’t use JavaScript to change style depending on screen size, use media queries. Hide your menu on small screens, but force it visible when user clicked on the button. You should toggle a class rather than changing the "display" property directly from the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
I hide menu links on small screen, but show them on big screen:

```
.menu
  li.menu-item
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
  .is-active
    display: block !important
@include media($medium-screen-up) 
  li.menu-item
    list-style-type: none
    display: inline-block !important
    float: right;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px
    @include position(relative, -50px null null null)
```

Then with jQuery I can toggle class for menu links:

```
// Burger menu for small screen
  $('#menuButton').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    $('li.menu-item').toggleClass('is-active');
    $('ul.menu').toggleClass('is-active');
  });
```